# Native+JS accessible redux store for react-native

Tags: react-native

Our team is looking for some implementation of store for redux that will be accessible from native code too.

Basically we want to create observers not only with js, but also with java/objective-c (so it should support js and native callbacks). Also, ability to create native reducers are also desirable, but isn't very important now.

So, maybe there are any implementations exist? Or someone dug same area and want to share their experience.

What we have already found:

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5102 -- attempt to share native function in js global namespace
2. https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-eval -- call js function from native code and **get results** (with existing approach in RN you just may send an event into js runtime, but cannot get result)
3. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1180 -- an old ticket about extending JSExecutor
4. https://github.com/wix/react-native-invoke -- call native function from js without wrapping it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no public solution available, so we've decided to develop own solution.

You can find it here: https://github.com/tipsi/native-store

It is currently support subscription and update from native code and javascript. Native middlewares aren't supported for now.